# Unable to change icon color in layout file for a FloatingActionButton on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, material-components-android

So, I have this layout file with the following skeleton:

```
<layout>
  <CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
    ... some tags and stuff ...
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
    .... nested scroll view stuff
    </NestedScrollView>
    <!-- Finally! Here comes.... -->
    <FloatingActionButton>
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/someDarkBlueColor"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_white_camera" />
        ... closing tags and stuff ....
```

ic_white_camera is as follows:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/colorWhite" android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="@color/colorWhite" android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4L4,4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L22,6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2L9,2zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z"/>
</vector>
```

**@color/colorWhite** is.. You guessed. White...

However android insists on rendering the camera icon in **black**!

I've tried adding `android:tint="@color/colorWhite"`. No go..

Added `android:foregroundTint="@color/colorWhite"` and... Nada!

Still getting this:

[image: Pesky camera in black]

Any clues on this one?

Best regards to y'all.. :-)

Comment: Did you try using app:tint="@color/colorWhite" instead of "android:tint"? If you use FloatingActionButton that in com.google.android.material package, you should add app:tint instead of android:tint

Comment: Perfect! That nailed it. Thanks a lot!

I wonder why it simply ignored the white color I've added inside ic_white_camera.xml...

Comment: (Now... How do I flag this question as answered??)

Comment: I added this as an answer. You may  flag this as answered if you could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `FloatingActionButton` that in `com.google.android.material` package, you should add `app:tint` instead of `android:tint`. Then in your xml you should be using `app:tint="@color/colorWhite"` instead of using `android:tint="@color/colorWhite"`.

Answer (score 1):

The right [attributes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md) are:

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_white_camera"
      app:tint="@color/colorWhite"
      app:backgroundTint="@color/someDarkBlueColor"/>
```

[image]

The `app:srcCompat` is important to work with [`VectorDrawable`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-vector-assets-in-android-apps-4318fd662eb9).

Answer (score 0):

I don't ensure what effect is your really want, but you could try to comment or delete this line:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/someDarkBlueColor"
```

Or adjust the value of `someDarkBlueColor`.

Comment: I wanted the camera to be white. Khalana Chinthaka solved the issue for me.